# Sorting contacts based on recently used/most used/urgency in AddressBook iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sorting, abaddressbook

I need to sort contacts in user's device based on recently used/most used/urgency and display them in a single view(not as in the phone app where these are displayed in separate tabs). I have researched about this but only got to know about sorting contacts alphabetically. Does the AddressBook framework allow this or is there some other way around? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**No**. Unfortunately, there is no way of knowing if a record has been  recently used or not.

However, you can sort records in the address book using the properties specified below:

[image: AdressBook Record Properties]
Here is a simple example of sorting records based on the creation date in descending order.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, NULL);

ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {

    NSArray *allPeople = CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef));

    NSArray *sortedPeople = [allPeople sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id aRecord, id otherRecord) {
        ABRecordRef aRecordRef = (__bridge ABRecordRef)aRecord;
        ABRecordRef otherRecordRef = (__bridge ABRecordRef)otherRecord;

        NSDate *aRecordCreationDate = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(aRecordRef, kABPersonCreationDateProperty));
        NSDate *otherRecordCreationDate = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(otherRecordRef, kABPersonCreationDateProperty));

        return [aRecordCreationDate compare:otherRecordCreationDate];
    }];
});

CFRelease(addressBookRef);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have found a solution First we create Abaddressbook and register it with changes callback like this

> 1)ABAddressBookRef ntificationaddressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();
>
> 2)ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(ntificationaddressbook,addressBookChanged, self);

and when you will make a change in any contact (modified,open,edit etc).
then its callback will call its delegate like this

> 3)void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef reference, 
>                           CFDictionaryRef dictionary, 
>                           void *context)
>
> {
>
> /// Address book is changed
>
> // Now you can Implement logic
>
> 1-First of all get the change date and time which is now. from [NSdate date].
>
> this will be the change date/time of a record
>   }

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Smart answer. But this will only gives history after application has been first launched.

Comment: sorry I did not understand your comment ?